# Jquery / Json UI autocomplete Airport code

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jsonp, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Im trying to use a Web Service to set an Airport code using Jquery UI autocomplete:

The WS is:
http://airportcode.riobard.com - http://airportcode.riobard.com/search?q=dallas&fmt=JSON

I can't create the autocomplete, here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://airportcode.riobard.com",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    fmt: "JSONP",
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.code + (item.name ? ", " + item.location : "") + ", " + item.location,
                            value: item.code
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
});
</script>




 <!-- HTML Code is -->

<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="city">Your city: </label>
    <input id="city" />

</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
    Result:
    <div id="log" style="height: 50px; width: 200px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, the data source you're using **does not support JSONP**. You can't just grab an arbitrary JSON data source and tell jQuery it's JSONP and expect it to work. The server must be configured to take a callback argument that it appends to the response, calling your code when it completes and is injected onto the page.

You can get around this by using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) or writing your own server-side code that calls the service.

Here's an example using YQL:

```
function buildQuery(term) {
    return "select * from json where url = 'http://airportcode.riobard.com/search?fmt=JSON&q=" + encodeURI(term) + "'";
}

function makeRequest(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
        data: {
            q: buildQuery(request.term),
            format: "json"
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            var airports = [];
            if (data && data.query && data.query.results && data.query.results.json && data.query.results.json.json) {
                airports = data.query.results.json.json;
            }

            response($.map(airports, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.code + (item.name ? ", " + item.location : "") + ", " + item.location,
                    value: item.code
                };
            }));
        },
        error: function () {
            response([]);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#airport").autocomplete({
        source: makeRequest,
        minLength: 2
    });
});​
```

So instead of calling the web service directly, we'll ask YQL to make the request and return a result. YQL acts as a wrapper, making an otherwise inaccessible web service accessible via JSONP.

In the `success` method, we have to go through several properties to finally access the data. After we do that, we can format the results in a way that the autocomplete widget expects (with `$.map`).

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BQxw4/40/

Comment: Thank you. Your example works fine and What you wrote makes me total sense. I'm just trying to learn all about jquery and web services, but is quite long topic.

I just added a line: 

term = encodeURIComponent(term);

because if you look cities with blank spaces in the name, it appears not to exist because the blan space needs to be %20

Best.

Comment: It doesn't work with spaces. I mean, for example, New York. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I made a slight modification cause the code above has a little bug, when there is only one json object the tree structure changes,try this fix for when there is only one object.

```
if (data && data.query && data.query.results && data.query.results.json && data.query.results.json.json) {
                airports = data.query.results.json.json;
            }else if( data && data.query && data.query.results && data.query.results.json ){
                airports = data.query.results;
            }
                jQuery.makeArray(airports);
```